# Get number of records of current week with timestamp

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a field called created time with type bigint. In there the unix timestamp is stored.

I need to create a query where I can get the sum of all records created on the current week.

I've never worked with timestamps previously so any help will be good thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm sure someone will come along and tell you that table create statement will be helpful to help you. It would also be good to know what you have tried. What specific problems are you encountering?

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp could not be converted to datetime. The timestamp is a row version that is not the row change date.

therefore, you can't count the records per week with this type of column.

Comment: The data saved on that field is the unixtime of the created date

Answer (score 0):

Try now...I Solve it..

SELECT * FROM store where db_timeframe_table='Weekly' and db_datetime_table>=(CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 week);

Comment: Well formatted answers get more attention on Stack-overflow. I suggest you format any code fragments so they stand out from normal text. More information here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer